# (Assembly NASM says "unable to open include file 'include.inc'"

Tags: assembly, nasm

I was finishing a small project that I had in mind(thanks to Tinkernut)to make a small operating system using Assembly. I made it from scratch and when I was done with the main files,I thought of adding some programs into the OS. so,i 
MADE a edit.asm file(Note:The spaces are part of the code):

```
; ------------------------------------------------------------------
; RhalexOS Text Editor 
; ------------------------------------------------------------------


    BITS 16
    %INCLUDE 'rhalexdev.inc'
    ORG 32768
```

(Everything else has been removed since it has nothing to do with the problem at hand)

But when I do this(I do have NASM installed): nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin

I get this:
edit.bin.7: Unable to open include file 'rhalexdev.inc'

I have been stuck here for an hour.Please help me.

Comment: And where is rhalexdev.inc located relative to edit.asm?

Comment: @Michael it's with the edit.asm file.

Comment: That line works for me. Are you assembling on an OS that doesn't support long filenames?

Comment: Nope,since it's Windows 7 that I am using to run NASM.

Comment: That's a *lot* of code to show us. Maybe try to come up with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i tried after I posted this,but sadly,the program requires every bit of code shown.

Comment: GUYS,I FOUND A SOLUTION.

Comment: Oh,nevermind.Solution didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `%include "rhalexdev.inc"`. Also if it isn't in the current directory you can provide a search path with `-I/path/to/include/dir` just like with C. Also see [**NASM Docs**](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~comp03/nasm/nasmdoc2.html) -- Section `2.1.10`

Comment: So if you remove the lines under `text_entry` that detects `F2` and jumps to `save_file`, suddenly the code does compile just fine?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin i tried that,didn't work either.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever nope,that's not what i did since that section wasn't the problem.

Comment: But that's the point - there's a lot of code there that is probably **nothing** to do with your problem. That's why I suggested you reduce it down to the *smallest* example you can that still exhibits the problem and post that instead.

Comment: There must be something else. Are there any stray characters in the file (non-printing/DOS/CRLF type)? I literally use `%include "rkn32.inc.asm"` to include my includes in every NASM assembler file without any issue?? What editor are you using ? `npp` ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever there.Edited out everything else that has noting to do with the problem at hand.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin nope. I double-checked the code and there's no stray characters.

Comment: So if you highlight the .inc file in Windows, press F2, Ctrl-c and then paste that as the filename to include in your code you still get the same result? And you didn't set any weird permissions for the .inc file?

Comment: @Michael yes.And I never set any weird permissions on the file.

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but for the sake of argument, will you move the `%include "rhalexdev.inc"` to column `1` in the file. It shouldn't matter, but the preprocessor may be wanting the `%include` at the beginning of the line...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin still doesn't work.

Comment: We are at the end of my toolbox, Only thing left is the cure-all. [**Archlinux Download**](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) It **will** work then `:p`

Comment: Use FASM - it never has such problems.

Comment: Post screenshot of command window, containing: `dir rhalexdev.inc` output, `nasm` command and output. If all else fails, run [process monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) and look at what low-level operation `nasm` is trying to perform.

Comment: All Command Window Screenshots(I moved to WinXp to fasten my computer,Win7 made me lag a bit):http://imgur.com/a/zQitd
Oh,and @DavidC.Rankin, I don't know how to use this .iso that you linked me to. And johnfound, no.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more literal. That was a half-hearted joke suggesting you install Archlinux to fix the problem `:p`. I'll look at the screenshot. It has to be something related to either the editor or the windows nasm package you are using or something similar. I'll let you know if the screenshot discloses anything.

Answer (score 2):

Oh my goodness. The screenshot does disclose the problem. The problem is you are not compiling in the same directory as `rhalexdev.inc`.

You need to either change to the `c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programs\` directory before attempting to compile with `nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin` or you need to provide an `-i` include path when you try to compile in `c:\Program Files\nasm`. The problem with the `-i` solution is you will have to either **quote** or **escape** the include path name to handle the spaces in the directory names.

What I would do is create a directory under your `c:\Documents and Settings\your_account\My Documents\nasm` (or whatever name you choose). Then copy all the source files from `c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programs\` to `c:\Documents and Settings\your_account\My Documents\nasm`. Then in the `c:\Documents and Settings\your_account\My Documents\nasm` issue the `nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin` command.

I would not recommend compiling in the `Program Files` or `Administrator\Desktop` directories. You can, just not what I would recommend.

If you want to build in `c:\Program Files\nasm`, then you will need to try something like:

```
nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin -i'c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programs\'
```

as quoted above with the trailing `\`, or with spaces escaped:

```
nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin -ic:\Documents\ and\ Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS\ Making\programs\
```

I suspect this will take care of your problem.

Comment: Sorry if I DIDN'T see this earlier,I had some problems with the machine.Will try this solution.

Comment: I put the `rhalexdev.inc` file within the same directory as the `edit.asm` file.

Comment: And the directory that had `edit.asm` was `C:\Program Files\nasm\programs`

Comment: So they're in the same folder. So:`nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin -i'C:\Program Files\nasm\programs'` becomes `nasm programs\edit.asm -o programs/edit.bin -i'C:\Program Files\nasm\programs'`

Comment: And now, it still shows this: `programs\edit.asm:7: fatal: unable to open inclue file 'rhalexdev.inc'`

Comment: Oh no... When they are in the same directory, just `nasm edit.asm -o edit.bin` If you are trying to use `-i`, you may also have to play with what it takes to escape a space. It may take for example `-ic:\\\Documents\\ and\\ Settings\\\...` Path escapes on windows can be tricky, especially when trying to use Linux tools. That's why I said put everything in the same directory.

Comment: Think of it this way. If all files are in the same directory **no include path is necessary**. Only if **the include file** is **not** in the same directory **you are compiling in** (e.g. calling `nasm` in) do you need an **include path**. We'll get there... If you will post a link to the include file, I'll build it on my box to confirm for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-I includepath`.
Include a `/` or `\` separator at the end of `includepath` if you're using old NASM versions.

---

I am using NASM ver 2.07 and had the same problem. Like I was trying the -i option millions of times and I still got include file not found error. And my include file path was correct, I double checked.

No @David C. Rankin. It's not just like C; it is similar to C.

The problem is that old NASM version did the following when resolving relative include paths:

```
const char *rel_fpath = parseIncludeDirective();
const char *include_path = nextIncludedPath();
char *full_fpath = newString( strlen(rel_fpath) + strlen(include_path) + 1 );
sprintf(full_path,"%s%s",include_path,rel_fpath);
```

As you can see at line 4 they simply concatenate the two paths without adding a directory separator. Which means that...

```
c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programs
```

and

```
rhalexdev.inc
```

becomes

```
c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programsrhalexdev.inc
```

With a trailing `\` at the end of `...\programs\`, it will just work even in this old NASM version.  Newer NASM versions don't need this and will join strings with a directory separator between them.

Comment: So what's the actual answer?  That the path should end with a path-separator, like `nasm -i /foo/bar/` instead of just `-i /foo/bar`?  Or with backslashes if Windows requires it.  Or are you saying that it strips a trailing directory separator from the `-i` arg (like you're showing with ```...\programs\```)?  That would make `-i` entirely unusable so that seems implausible.  Unless it was just a bug in some versions around NASM 2.07, which is very old.  Current is 2.16.01

Comment: @PeterCordes Older versions of NASM do concatenate the `-I` string with the filename given to the `%include` directive, without placing a directory separator between the two. So usually you want to have the `-I` parameter have a trailing slash. (I think DOS and MSWindows do allow slash just as well as backslash.)

Comment: @PeterCordes you must be tired. After all my text and illustrations I dont see why I need to explain further. And I have no clue how you figured I could be implying the NASM program strips trailing directory seperator.

Comment: You're claiming that concatenating `"c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programs\"` with `"rhalexdev.inc"` produces `"...\programsrhalexdev.inc"`, which doesn't have the backslash after `programs` that was present in the code block you're showing. If that was real, something would have had to remove it.  Probably you meant to write `c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\OS Making\programs` in that code block. In which case your answer should mention that the fix is to include a trailing separator in the arg to `-I`; ecm says that worked even with old NASM

Comment: @PeterCordes Oh my! I really need some rest. I could have sworn I deleted that last seperator! My apologies and respects.

Comment: Sleep well.  I made the rest of the edits I was suggesting, to actually answer the question by showing what to do that will actually work.  (And thanks to @ecm for confirming the details of old vs. recent NASM behaviour, I edited to clarify that only older NASM versions have this pothole.)